# Getting an error when calling a function

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010

I am attempting to call a function but the error I am getting is **"The best overloaded method match for xxxx has some invalid arguments"**. When I hover over it, I get the option to "Generate method stub..."

The code causing the error is:

> ```
> if (oCustomerDAL.VerifyCustomerLoginID(ref oSubscriber))    { }
> ```

The related function is:

```
public bool VerifyCustomerLoginID(ref IAuthenticate oSystemUser)
```

How can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as the method uses the `ref` keyword, you need to also provide it when calling the method:

```
if (oCustomerDAL.VerifyCustomerLoginID(ref oSubscriber))    { }
```

(OP omited the `ref` before edit)

---

**Edit**. You should also check what type `oSubscriber` is. Ensure that it implements interface `IAuthenticate` as this is the interface that the method you're trying to call requires.

To do this find the definition of the class for which `oSubscriber` is an instance and ensure that it looks something like this (C#)

```
public class Subscriber : IAuthenticate
{
   ...
}
```

Comment: Does the class represented by `oSubscriber` implement `IAuthenticate`?

Comment: How would I ensure that the class implements IAuthenticate? Not too great at OOP....

Answer (score 5):

```
if (oCustomerDAL.VerifyCustomerLoginID(ref oSubscriber))    { }
```